# Why is a new post not shown in the Latest Topics Block after updating Advanced Forum?

Tags: blocks, nodes

I updated the version of the [Advanced Forum](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_forum) module today. I posted a new topic and now it doesn't show on a block I have in the side bar where latest created topics always used to show up.

What can be happening?

Comment: Apparently after some hours it showed up. I'm not sure why it takes hours to show up but, I guess that's how it works...

Comment: did you run the update.php, after you updated? `www.yoursite.com/update.php`

Answer (score 0):

Some problems get resolved just by being patient for a while. Some of those problems are caused by either of the following:

- You should have cleared the cache.
- Something required a cron job to run.

If such kinds of actions are not performed (eg because you're not aware they are needed), it is just a matter of time to get such problems resolved automagically ... as illustrated [in this specific comment (last paragraph)](https://www.drupal.org/node/1739982#comment-9322561) also.